# c++ memory troubleshooting

Tags: c++, memory

I'm writing some C++ code for an Arduino. I'm doing a for loop from 0 to 7 and when I print out the variables n and m they work fine. But once I remove the `//` from the line `ufo[i][n][m] = rumskib[n][m];` the values n and m will output values like:

n: 6
m: 3

n: 6
m: 4

n: 1030
m: 5

I'm having trouble understanding why I'm messing up my memory. Below is the relevant code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    antal_ufo++;
    int * ufo[8][8];
    *ufo[i] = new int[i];
    int n, m;
    for (n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
        for (m = 0; m < 8; m++) {
            Serial.print("n: ");
            Serial.println(n);
            Serial.print("m: ");
            Serial.println(m);
            Serial.println();
            Serial.println();
            //ufo[i][n][m] = rumskib[n][m];
            delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%2A+ufo%5B8%5D%5B8%5D - Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: `new int[i];` with `i = 0` looks interesting...

Comment: What's rumskib?

Comment: What's the purpose of `for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)`?

Comment: Apart from your code being incorrect (see other comments), since it's C++ you should be using std::vector<int>. It'll make things much less confusing for you. If you couple that with using at() for indexing then it will help you catch out of bounds errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get Undefined behaviour, because you allocate only `i` elements in array here `new int[i];` and it could happen anything when you try to write in `(i, j)` position, than you have UB.
UB means that values could be corrupted, you can get crash, infinity loop, or something another.
Use corresponding size of allocated memory.

Correctness code can be:

```
int K = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < K; i++) {
    antal_ufo++;
    auto ufo = new int[K][8][8];
    int n, m;
    for (n = 0; n < 8; n++) {
        for (m = 0; m < 8; m++) {
            ufo[i][n][m] = rumskib[n][m];
            delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for including suggestion code !
I now understand that the problem was with memory allocation. is the "auto" part integral to the code?

Comment: `auto` is part of C++ after 2011 year (C++11). Use it freely. Don't forget to clear memory with calling `delete[][][]` or with `std::shared_ptr`.

But better choose is using `std::vector<int>` instead of manually allocation and deallocation memory.

Answer (score 1):

You should figure out how pointers, indexing and scopes work. `ufo` variable gets out of scope after every iteration, `*ufo[i]` initializes item at [0][i] index with array of `i` `int`s, but expression `ufo[i][n][m]` access all uninitialized values at [i][n][m] range.